# Adding Class to Id's using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I press a button, my table is suppose to be replaced by a video but when I click the button, my table disappears and my video won't show up. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<script>
var checkContent = 0;
function contentChange(){
    if(checkContent == 0){
        $('#tableContent').addClass("hiddenContent");
        $('#videoContent').removeClass("hiddenContent");
        checkContent++;
    }else{
        $('#tableContent').removeClass("hiddenContent");
        $('#videoContent').addClass("hiddenContent");
        checkContent--;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you will have to share the html and any css also

Comment: other then the whole `checkContent` thing not being required, the jquery looks fine (although i'd suggest `toggleClass` rather then a `if/else` statement. can you show the html

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<button>Click</button>
<table id="tableContent"><tr><td>Table Content</td></tr></table>
<div id="videoContent" class="hiddenContent">Video Content</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( '#tableContent' ).toggleClass( "hiddenContent" );
  $( '#videoContent' ).toggleClass( "visiblecontent" );
});
```

CSS:

```
.hiddenContent{ display:none;}
.visiblecontent{ display: block; }
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnsskxge/).

Simple, but I don't know it is good for you.

Comment: i'd post your code with your answer with a explination of how it works. link only answer get voted down/closed

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me"></input>

<div id="someContent" hidden>Some Content</div>
<div id="videoContent">Video Content</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    var someContent = document.getElementById("someContent");
    var videoContent = document.getElementById("videoContent");

    if(someContent.hasAttribute("hidden")){
        someContent.removeAttribute("hidden");
        videoContent.setAttribute("hidden", "");
    }
    else{
        videoContent.removeAttribute("hidden");
        someContent.setAttribute("hidden", "");
    }
}
```

Try this if any good for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/bigneo/40vLxLnm/

Comment: Just realized Tomas Tomas answered it with less+better code :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the console in the browser (CTRL + SHIFT + J).

Also remove the

```
`enter code here`
```

if you didn't put it there on purpose.

If that still doesn't work you probably have an error in either your CSS or your HTML code.